# Retrieve data from jQuery Object

Tags: jquery

I am having problems with my jQuery object which I recieve from Ajax function.

```
console.log(data) ==> dumps {"isUnique":true}
```

and

```
console.log(data.isUnique) ==> dumps undefined
```

How should I get these "isUnique" data?

Code
Js:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       async: false,
       url: ...some url ,
       data: { 'email' : value },
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
             console.log(data.isUnique);
       }
 });
```

Comment: Can you paste the raw response here? Also the code you are using for the request.. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `data` is still a string, and not a javascript object? Because otherwise, this works just fine. See http://jsbin.com/qonutemedo/edit?js,console

Comment: var s = data.isUnique   or   var s = data["isUnique"]

Comment: I assume that your data is a string and not a javascript object.

Comment: Please show full context of where these logs are done in request.

Comment: Have you set the dataType of yout ajax-call to `json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dataType` is incorrect

Change

```
dataType: "text",
```

To

```
dataType: "json",
```

This will tell jQuery to parse the response to an object from string internally

Comment: Yea... that's why this happend. This answer is better than the last one :) thank you

Comment: Also never use `async:false`. It is terrible practice and you should see deprecation warning in your browser console.

Comment: What is this used for? I've just deleted it and my Ajax loading goes more fluently then before! :)

Comment: It completely blocks everything in the page until request completes. Just don't use it. Cause bad user experience

Comment: Yea! I could not write while loading. Tyvm, op answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as you're getting a JSON. You can use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var myValue = obj.isUnique;
```

As mentioned by charlietfl in the comments, you can easily avoid this by manually setting [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in the request.

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string).

...

> **"json"**: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also
>   rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.
>   (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', // or 'get' if you prefer.
    url: 'your_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.isUnique);
    }
});
```

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"isUnique":true}' );
alert( obj.isUnique);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need for this when use proper `dataType` for the request

Comment: @charlietfl - Yes, very true. The answer is based on the first information given by the OP.  I'll update my answer.